# Change activity or scroll activity when keyboard appear

Tags: android, xml, keyboard

I have an recycleview in the end of activity but i want,when keyboard appear on click **field_comment_form**
the activity goes up to the EditText and only `EditText` and `recycleview` will be seen
I already tried many ways including

**`windowSoftInputMode:adjustResize`**

my code of xml is below:

```
    <RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="3dp">

     <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/post_text_layout_card"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="1dp"
        app:cardElevation="5dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dp">

            <include
                android:id="@+id/post_author_layout"
                layout="@layout/include_post_author"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/star_layout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/post_author_layout"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/post_author_layout"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/star_cmnt"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_create_black_24dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/post_num_stars_cmnt"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    tools:text="7" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <include
                layout="@layout/include_post_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/post_author_layout"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/comment_form"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/post_text_layout_card"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/cmnt_post_box_back"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1.0">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/field_comment_text"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.8"
            android:breakStrategy="balanced"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:hint="Write a comment..."
            android:maxLines="2" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_post_comment"
            style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:text="Post" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_comments"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/comment_form"
        tools:listitem="@layout/item_comment" />
</RelativeLayout>`
```

[screenshot is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUpKD.png)

Comment: post screen shot also

Comment: @Rahul i have tagged the screenshot in post.please see it

Comment: why don't u make card visibility gone whenever keyboard popup

Comment: how can i achieve this @Rahul